# About an equivalent to Tutte's 5-flow Conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A while back I remember reading that F. Jaeger proved that Tutte's $5$-flow conjecture is equivalent to a statement about the co-planarity of a certain set of points in some euclidean space. But I cannot remember the exact statement and I cannot find it anywhere.

Does anyone out there remember the equivalent statement or know an accessible reference to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably thinking of the paper:

F. Jaeger, [Geometrical aspects of Tutte’s 5-ﬂow conjecture](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=737025).
Graphs and other combinatorial topics, Teubner-Texte Math, 1983.

The following is taken from the MathSciNet review, which in turn is taken from the author's summary of the paper:

*``Let $G$ be a cubic bridgeless graph with $V(G)=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. To each orientation $\overrightarrow{G}$ of $G$ we associate the point $x=(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x_i = d_{\overrightarrow{G}}^{+}(v_i)-d_{\overrightarrow{G}}^{-}(v_j)$ for $i=(1,\ldots,n)$. Let $B$ be the resulting set of points. We prove that $G$ satisfies Tutte's $5$-flow conjecture if and only if $B$ contains three points $x,x',x''$ such that $x,x',x'',-x,-x',-x''$ are six co-planar points in general position, or $G$ is bipartite."*

Comment: I have no MathSciNet access. Could you be kind and post the equivalent statement here. Thanks.

Comment: @hbm, I have updated the answer.